# How to properly reverse rrange in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I try to reverse the rrange of a polar gnuplot plot. According to the [documentation](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_5.0/gnuplot.pdf) (p. 173f) this can be achieved by swapping min and max values of the range definition or by using the `reverse` keyword in autoscale mode. 
Neither one nor the other variant gives the results that I want.

The code:

```
set polar
set grid polar 30
set angle degrees
set size square

# case 1
set rrange [0:90]
# case 2
set rrange [90:0]
# case 3
set rrange [*:*] reverse

plot "-" u 1:2 w p pt 7 ps 3
0 30
30 60
60 45
e
```

The results:

The first picture shows a range of [0:90], the second one the range of [90:0] where no point is visible at all.
Plot three shows the output of the reverse setting.

[image: <code>rrange[0:90]</code>]
[image: <code>rrange[90:0]</code>]
[image: <code>rrange[0:90] reverse</code>]

As the documentation for rrange states

> [...] no point with radius greater than < rmax > will be plotted.

the behavior of case 2 is totally comprehensible. On the other hand, case 3 should give the same result according to the following:

> The reverse option reverses the direction of an autoscaled axis. For example, if the data values range from 10 to 100, it will autoscale to the **equivalent** of set xrange [100:10].

There seems to be some inconsistency between the documentation and the actual behavior of gnuplot.

This leads me to my question: How can I plot a diagram with the radius axis ranging from 90 in the middle to 0 at the outer circle?

**EDIT**

A small explanation of the application background:
What I want to visualize is a 2D top view of a sphere with equally spaced latitudes ([Azimuthal equidistant projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azimuthal_equidistant_projection)). There, the center represents a pole with 90 degrees of latitude which decreases along the radius.

Comment: What you want to do is weird from a mathematical point of view. Although gnuplot permits it, I don't understand what a polar plot with `rmin`≠0 means. If you have a specific application in mind with a clear meaning, I would calculate the 'standard' r-theta coordinates (with rmin=0) and re-label the tics (`set rtics ("90" 0, "0" 90)`)

Comment: I believe there is something wrong in gnuplot here (5.0pl3 here). "reverse" should work as expected, as should the explicit range setting. I think you should file a bug report on this. Although @Joce is right, this seems rarely useful.;-)

Comment: @Joce I added a small description of what I want to achieve. It seems that your suggestion to do a re-calculation of all points and a re-labeling is a way to solve that.

Comment: That's much clearer now! I think relabeling is the most logical thing to do, both from an IT and a geometry perspective: the labels describe the spherical coordinate system, but the 2D plot is done in regular polar coordinates (hence start from... the pole !)

Comment: Note that tics relabeling can be automated with a `sprintf` and a `for` loop, in case you don't invariably have the full [0,90] interval.

Answer (score 3):

As a side comment, note also that the behaviour of the reverse keyword has been changed in Gnuplot 5 vs Gnuplot 4:
http://gnuplot.info/ReleaseNotes_5_0.html

"set xrange [0:1] reverse" does not work any more, you have to write instead "set xrange [1:0]".